# Default initializer of C and C++ languages of boolean types on GCC compiler is 64 instead of 0. It's compiler bug?

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I'm studying D language and simultaneously doing comparison to C and C++ languages.It works fine both dmd and gdc compilers,but when I tested on gcc compiler,I found a thing that looks like bug of GCC compiler,the default initializer of boolean type instead of 0/false see the following code:

**C++ code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    bool b;
    cout << b << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

**G++ compiler(gcc version 4.4.3 (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5.1):**

```
g++ -Wall -pedantic test.cpp
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: test.cpp:7: warning: ‘b’ is used
uninitialized in this function 
./a.out 64
```

**C code(foo.c):**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define bool _Bool

int main(int argc, char * args[])
{
    bool b;
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

**gcc compiler**

```
gcc-4.6 -Wall -pedantic a.c
foo.c: In function ‘main’:
foo.c:9:8: warning: ‘b’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
./a.out
64
```

**tcc compiler**

```
tcc -Wall foo.c
./a.out
0
```

**clang compiler**

```
clang -Wall -pedantic foo.c     
./a.out
0
```

Can someone explain the gcc behavior?

Comment: Hint: Look at the warnings. C++ does ***not*** specify that variables are initialized to anything by default.

Comment: Can someone remove -1? it's real question.. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default initialization in C++ for basic types means "uninitialized". That is, any value can be there. You got 64 because that just happened to be in that memory location.

If you want to do value initialization, then you need to use `bool()`:

```
bool b = bool(); //Now is false.
```

Value initialization effectively means initializing basic types to zero.

C++11 makes this rather cleaner:

```
bool b{}; //Now is false.
```

Answer (score 6):

As your warning messages indicate, you are not initializing the local variables before you use them, so their content will be undefined.

Comment: @Jack: No, it's a C/C++ thing.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But why the `64` number?

Comment: @Jack, Because that's what happens to be on the stack at the moment.  If you really want to know, you could trace through the `crt0` startup code to see what leaves that value there; but you are asking about behavior that is explicitly undefined.